# Is there a way to set javascript mouse event order?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a jQuery plugin which intercept several mouse events (mousedown, mouseup, mouseout, click) for different purposes.

However sometimes it doesn't work correctly due to one event fired before the other.

I can't really reproduce it, so please understand I made some research (for eaxmple I found http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-eventgroupings ).

How do I set **mouse order firing** (e.g. mouseup after click)? I can use jQuery if necessary.

Comment: The event order is always the same. What are you trying to do?

Comment: A `click` is *always* a `mousedown` followed by a `mouseup`.  If you are holding the mouse button down, then moving the cursor away before letting go, then it probably won't count as a `click`.

Comment: But is `mouseup` guaranteed to fire before `click`, or vice versa?

Comment: @Dunnie `click` is the complete action: `mousedown` + `mouseup`, so in essence you are expecting the same event to be fired when it comes to listening to mouseup events from both `click` and `mouseup`

Comment: @AGE Not necessarily: you might want to bind one event to `mouseup`, and another to `click`. I can imaging there could be unusual scenarios where you want to do that.

Comment: @Dunnie you know that might be a good question for SO ;-)

Comment: @Dunnie the are many possible scenarios for that, For example I found useful in my jQuery plugin to have both mouseup and click

Comment: (sorry, can't provide an example right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the ordering is browser dependent, so you can't rely on a specific sequence.

Would setting/checking flags work for you? e.g.

```
<button id="myButton">Click Me!</button>

<script>
    function doSomething() {
        alert("Hello world!");
    }

    var mouseUpFired = false;
    var clickFired = false;
    // etc

    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        mouseUpFired = true;
        if(mouseUpFired && clickFired /*etc*/) {
            doSomething();
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        clickFired = true;
        if(mouseUpFired && clickFired /*etc*/) {
            doSomething();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: as I said, it's very difficult to reproduce it but you are probably right about browser-dependence. I think your solution is good

Comment: however, I was thinking, your solution would lead to non-firing event. For example: let's say that when .click() trigger is run, if mouseUpFired == false, it will just skip the doSomething() which is definitely a non-desirable scenario

Comment: @dragonmnl That depends on what your exact logic needs to be. My example is only really an idea or a starting point. For example, you could remove the `if` statement from the `click` handler, and run `doSomething()` on every click, but only run it on the `mouseup` if a `click` had occurred before.